# "adb is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, adb

I'm trying to setup react native and get the emulator running, but I keep getting this error when I try to run "adb" in the terminal, and when I open the emulator, it says "adb is not found".

`'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I have platform tools installed, [I have all the things I should have installed for it to work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYBco.png)

I also have all the paths in both environment variables and bash profile in vscode. I don't know what else to try. [Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAvF6.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have just installed everything your PATH may not be updated in app processes. Log off and on or reboot your system and then retry.